# Access data send by xhr request in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

Im sending some text from a textbox to node.js express server by XMLHttpRequest:

```
var text = document.getElementById("textBox").value;
    console.log(text);
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 || xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("textBox").value =xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://127.0.0.1:3000/",true);
    xmlhttp.send(text);
```

My question is how to access it in my server :

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var qs = require('querystring');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
// start endle req\res
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.post('/', function(req,res){
    console.log("request method :" + req.method);
    res.end("OK");
});

// listen at local host:3000
var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

The string appears as request payload and i dont want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Because of how bodyParser accepts the body of a request, you have to set the request header "Content-Type" to 'application/json' for your request to work properly. This is very simple to accomplish; a simple
`xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')` will do the trick.

Comment: I think you made a minor error:

Instead of `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application.json')` it should be `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json')`

Answer (score -1):

You can read the request body via `req.body`:

```
app.post('/', function(req,res){
  console.log("request method :" + req.method);
  console.log("request body :" + req.body);
  res.end("OK");
});
```